# Kotlin Coroutines: NullPointerException on androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm attempting to use kotlin Coroutines for fetching data from a Database using androidx.room artifact. I've analysed the code and I'm yet to find a solution to the problem.

I'm getting a null exception on `tonight` object which I already set to be nullable. I shouldn't be getting a null exception on a nullable object.

This is the ViewModel class from where I'm writing logic for fetching data

**SleepTrackerViewModel.kt**

```
package com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepDatabaseDao
import com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality.database.SleepNight
import com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality.formatNights
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

/**
 * ViewModel for SleepTrackerFragment.
 */
class SleepTrackerViewModel(
    val database: SleepDatabaseDao,
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    init {
        initializeTonight()
    }

    /**
     * [tonight] is the object that holds the most recent [SleepNight]
     */
    private var tonight = MutableLiveData<SleepNight?>()

    /**
     * Get all the nights from the database
     */
    private val nights = database.getAllNights()
    val nightsString = Transformations.map(nights) { nights ->
        formatNights(nights, application.resources)
    }

    private fun initializeTonight() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            tonight.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getTonightFromDatabase(): SleepNight? {
        var night = database.getTonight()
        if (night?.endTimeMilli != night?.startTimeMilli) {
            // If the start and end times are not the same, meaning that the night has already been completed
            night = null
        }
        return night
    }

    /**
     * Function to start tracking a new SleepNight
     */
    fun onStartTracking() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val newNight = SleepNight()
            insert(newNight)
            //assign newNight to tonight as the most recent SleepNight
            tonight.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun insert(night: SleepNight) {
        database.insert(night)
    }

    fun onStopTracking() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val oldNight = tonight.value ?: return@launch
            oldNight.endTimeMilli = System.currentTimeMillis()
            update(oldNight)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun update(night: SleepNight) {
        database.update(night)
    }

    fun onClear() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            clear()
            tonight.value = null
        }
    }

    suspend fun clear() {
        database.clear()
    }
}
```

**The Error Message**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality, PID: 21352
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null 
object reference
        at 
com.google.samples.apps.trackmysleepquality.sleeptracker.SleepTrack
erViewModel$initializeTonight$1.invokeSuspend(SleepTrackerViewMod
el.kt:56)
        at 
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(Contin
uationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: Put that init block below your `tonight` declaration. See if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of a couple of unexpected ways you can get a NullPointerException in Kotlin. You have an `init` block that calls the function `initializeTonight()` before `tonight` has been initialized. When a class is instantiated, all the property initializations and `init` blocks are called in order from top to bottom.

You might think it's safe because the value of `tonight` is set inside a coroutine, but by default `viewModelScope` synchronously starts running part of the launched coroutine because it uses `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`. Your `getTonightFromDatabase()` is calling a suspend function too, but that database might also be using `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` and be capable of returning a result without actually suspending.

I would change your code as follows. Remove the `init` block and `initializeTonight` functions. Declare `tonight` like this:

```
private var tonight = MutableLiveData<SleepNight?>().also {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        it.value = getTonightFromDatabase()
    }
}
```

Also, I would make it `val` instead of `var`. There shouldn't be a reason to ever replace it, so making it `var` is error-prone.

Comment: This also worked. The explanation was useful

Answer (score 3):

@Tenfour04 covered the issue that's causing it, but I just wanted to point out you're reading the error message wrong, and it probably sent you in the wrong direction:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null 
object reference
```

That means you're trying to call `setValue` on a `null` object - i.e. `null.setValue(whatever)`. It's not your `MutableLiveData` *contents* that are null (as you said, the value has a nullable type so that should be fine) - it's the `MutableLiveData` itself, which is what you call `setValue` on.

You don't see this one too often in Kotlin (since it does its own null checking and throws a different "oi this shouldn't be null" message) but it can happen!

Comment: The explanation was very relevant to my work. Thanks